# a function which is monotone in an open interval but it is not continuously differentiable at that interval.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Can you  give an example of a function $f(x)$  which is differentiable but not continuously differentiable  and there exists a nbd $N$ around a point $c$ such that $f'(x) >(<) 0   \forall x \in N $ and $f'(x)$ is not continuous at the point $c$?

I am basically trying to search a function which is monotone in an open interval but it is not continuously differentiable at that interval.

Can anyone please help me to find that kind of a function?

Comment: Duplicate of [285944](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285944/is-a-monotone-differentiable-function-continuously-differentiable)

Comment: A function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ can be  increasing and differentiable and such that $\{f'(x): |x|<r\}$ is unbounded above for every $ r>0.$  Then $f(x)=x+g(x)$ is strictly increasing and differentiable and $f'(x)=1+g'(x)\ge 1$ for all $x,$ but $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
10x + x^2 \cos \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) & x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Take $N = (-0.5 , 0.5)$ and $f'(0) =10 , f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in N$, and $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases}$$
Then
$$g'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases},$$
hence $g'$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$. Note that, on the interval $(-1, 1)$, we have
$$|g'(x)| \le 2|x| \cdot\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| + \left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \le 3.$$
Hence, if we let
$$f(x) = 4x + g(x),$$
then $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$, and on the interval $(-1, 1)$, we have
$$f'(x) = 4 + g'(x) \ge 4 - |g'(x)| \ge 4 - 3 > 0.$$